# Azure Search data consistency when posting to index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to understand what consistency guarantees Azure Search provides.

**Scenario:**
Let's say I'm posting documents sequentially to Azure Search REST API:

1. *doc1*
2. *doc2*
3. *doc3*

**Questions**

1. I issue a query and *doc3* is returned. Does it imply that *doc1* and *doc2* are also present in the index? E.g., should I be concerned about data replication not being completed yet, etc.?
2. If POST request returns, is it 100% guaranteed that the posted document is available to search, hence will immediately be found by any client querying the index?
3. Does any of the behavior related to consistency depend on the tier used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Azure Search guarantees that eventually all documents show up, but not that readers will see them show up in order (no monotonic reads).

2) No. If you see HTTP status 200 from the indexing request, it means the data is durable (we won’t lose it) but not that it’s searchable. It may take a few seconds to be searchable depending the load.

3) All tiers expose an eventual consistency model. There might be minor differences in typical timings/sequence among tiers due to differences in how data is partitioned, but these are differences that you shouldn’t take a dependency on since they are variable.

Comment: Thanks! That's very useful.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to detect that eventual consistency is achieved, so that clients can be 100% sure that they will find data which they posted.
Do you have any recommendations how to achieve that?

I could add a few seconds delay after save as you mention in 2), but is there any SLA on how long it takes for data to become searchable?

Comment: It may take a few seconds to be searchable depending the load. Question, why do you need to give a 100% guarantee on when data is searchable

Comment: 100% guarantee for data to be searchable is one of the requirements for the system I'm working on. Any ideas on how to achieve that are highly appreciated.